# android-how to detect my application bug and fix them

Tags: android

I've made my app and publish it out . It's been downloaded about 7000 times . it running from api 8 to api 19 .

Before publishing ,I've tested it on 3 different real devices (not virtual) and it was ok .

Now ,about 10 users says that app crashes on different parts and it's bothering me .

How can I find these issues without having real devices ? does virtual devices works the same ? is there any other way that I could find out the problem ? any way I can report the issue from the app and solve it ?

thanks

Comment: Technically the virtual devices are made to emulate the real devices so they should result in the same errors as the real devices. Another way to see the crash problem though is adding some reporting code to your app, like email you the log file when the app crashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this so there is no precise answer.

But the way I do this is through google analytics. I extend the Application class and just send uncaught exceptions to google analytics,

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();

    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler (new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e)
        {
            tracker.send(new HitBuilders.ExceptionBuilder()
            .setDescription(Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()))
            .setFatal(true)
            .build());
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    });
    //...
```

But as I said you can handle this your own way.

Answer (score 1):

Import analytics into your app

Acra,http://try.crashlytics.com/sdk-android/,
Flurry.

That will show where is your app crashing

Answer (score 1):

Use bugsense, it will provide you the detailed crash report

Go here and sign up and a create a new project
and follow the instructions

https://mint.splunk.com

Answer (score 0):

Here are some crash solutions:
https://github.com/ACRA with a guide ->http://www.toptal.com/android/automated-android-crash-reports-with-acra-and-cloudant

or check https://try.crashlytics.com/

Of course you could just ask the people what device it crashed on and hopefully re-create the bug so that you may find a solution. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can view crashes and ANRs in the Play Store developer console: [play.google.com/apps/publish/](http://play.google.com/apps/publish/). This will give you a starting point at least.